# @page rule not helping get content take full width of a paper

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page

I am currently working on a table that i have to print out on a paper. 
I need the table to span the full width of the paper. I want to print on(A4 landscape).  This is the CSS code i used.

```
@media print{
  .noprint{display:none;} 
   table{width:100% !important ;}
   tr,td,thead,th{width:auto;}
}

@page{
  size: landscape;
  Margin:0px;
}
```

I have tried adding `!important` on the rules but still does not work. 
Can anyone help me out please? I don't understand where the problem could be.

Comment: Can you provide the html code?

Comment: The table is generated in PHP.  The table gets long too. If this helps i have used w3.Css framework for most of the styling but this framework does not have a print function so i don't think its messing up anything. Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

Got to solve the problem. 
All i did was remove the text overflow `text-overflow :hidden; white-space:nowrap;`
This has helped prevent my table from shrinking down due to overflow in the data when i tried to print it. 
Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem